# The 'configurable' method of 'value.subject.name.strategy' class is not called

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

When I use schema-registry in kafka-connect, I added properties like this:

```
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=https://schema-registry-host:8082
value.converter.auto.register.schemas=false
value.converter.schema.registry.ssl.truststore.location=/path
value.converter.use.latest.version=true
value.converter.latest.compatibility.strict=false
value.converter.key.subject.name.strategy=com.test.MySubjectNameStrategy
value.converter.value.subject.name.strategy=com.test.MySubjectNameStrategy //extends SubjectNameStrategy class
```

Schema-registry works fine. 'MySubjectNameStrategy.subjectName' method works fine. But 'MySubjectNameStrategy.configurable' was not called at all.
"MySubjectNameStrategy" needs to get parameters in .properties file. Can someone please help?

Comment: Do you mean the `configure` method? That is a warning and shouldn't prevent anything from running if you didn't override it. You've not shown any properties that should get passed to it

Comment: The same here. 

`public void configure(Map<String, ?> config)` is not called.

Confluent Kafka 5.3.0